# Github autopilot Runtime Status: Not yet actived

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I have done installing github autopilot and merging with my source github account and granting permission for the same. But still in VSCode it is not working. Upon clicking on the extension, in the Runtime Status tab, it is showing: Not yet Active. What should I do in order to start using github copilot in my VSCode?

I tried connecting with my github account.

Comment: Do you have an active copilot subscription?

Comment: Yes,
PS: After hours of struggle, I installed the previous version of the extension in VS Code and it worked!